# how to order column in Multi-columns index for best performance in Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, indexing

Let's say I have transactions table in a mysql database, I want to create a multi-column index on 3 columns reference, kind and status. 
I have this request that I am trying to speed up :
`Transaction.where(parent_ref: merchant_ref, kind: 'OFFER',status: 1)`                                which performs the following SQL :

```
SELECT `merchant_transactions`.* FROM `merchant_transactions` 
WHERE `merchant_transactions`.`parent_ref` = '1-0001' 
 AND `merchant_transactions`.`kind` = 'BATCH_BET' 
 AND `merchant_transactions`.`status` = 1
```

The parent_ref column can take a really wide variety of values so if I have 1M records in that table I will have 500K different references. Status can only take 6 different values and kind only 3.
What will be the best order for the columns in my index for optimal performance.
Does the spread of values in my columns have an impact ? intuitively I would say that I would need to start with the column with the lowest spread of values. In that example I would thus do index(kind, status, reference).
Are there any other factors related to the values in my tables to take into account when figuring out the order of columns for my index ?

Comment: Yes, the order of columns in the index has everything to do with the queries you need to run, which will use that index. You cannot design an index without knowing the queries first. You haven't described any specific queries in your question.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have queries which use the 3 fields above that Im trying to speed up. I want to know if it's smarter to put first the columns that have the narrowest spread of data values or if it doesnt change anything

Comment: I'm not going to try to guess what your queries look like.

Comment: @BillKarwin I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now that you've shared the query, we can see that you reference all three columns in your WHERE clause, all three predicates are doing equality comparisons, and the expression in the WHERE clause uses only `AND` operations.

There are no more exotic parts of the query like `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `DISTINCT`, etc. to complicate the optimization of this query.

Given these conditions, my experience is that the order of columns hardly matters. If there's any difference, it's barely perceptible.

I'd put the column that is unique first, based on some assumption that it's most selective and therefore narrows down the search most effectively. But I'm not sure it would make any noticeable difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, each of 3 columns is tested with `=`, and they are `ANDd` together.  So build a 3-column composite with those 3 columns.  The order of the columns will not matter for this query.  Contrary to what others may say, "cardinality" of the individual columns does not matter in a composite `INDEX`.

See my [*indexing cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)